# yii2: var_dump variable that utf-8 before run die();

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I want a `var_dump` a variable and add a `die();` after that

Why does my variable have problem ?

```
  var_dump($subject);                           
        die();
```

> string(71) " Ú©Ø§Ø±Ø¨Ø± Ø¹Ø²ÛŒØ² ÙØ±ØµØª Ù„Ø¨Ø§Ù„Ø¨ ØªØ§ÛŒÛŒØ¯ Ø´Ø¯ "

Comment: I think it can be a problem on the client-side. Did you set correctly lang and charset attributes of HTML-page?

Comment: yes! only when i  use var_dump in controller or model  utf-8 have problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public function actionCreate() {


        $model = new Opportunity();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            echo("<html lang=''><meta charset='UTF-8' />   <body>");
            var_dump($model->project_control_id);
            var_dump($model->projectType);
            echo "</body></html>";

            die();
        }
```